# How can I parse a HTML attribute value out of XMLHttpRequest.responseText?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The below JS function does Ajax request and retrieves HTML in `obj.responseText`. My issue is that I need to extract the value of `id` inside the `span` into `notify_id` var. I just don't know how to get that done.

This is the HTML to lookup:

HTML:

```
<span id="1034"></span><img src="./images/icons/post_icon.png">
```

JS:

```
function func()
{
    obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    obj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(obj.readyState == 4)
            jQuery.jGrowl(obj.responseText, { 
                sticky:true,
                close: function(e,m) {
                    notifyClosed(notify_id);

                }
            });
    }
    obj.open("GET", "notifications.php?n=1", true);
    obj.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but an `id` may not begin with a number.http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2 : "D and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")."

Comment: If you're already using `jQuery`, why don't you use its [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) instead of those 5 lines of ajaxical verbosity?

Comment: i know, i will worry about that later. but my major issue is in parsing obj.responseText

Comment: @BalusC, even tho that still wont solve the id extraction issue

Comment: D'oh, I didn't post it as an **answer**, but as a **comment** :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery:

```
var responseText = '<span id="1034"></span><img src="./images/icons/post_icon.png">';
var spanId = $('<div>').html(responseText).find('span').attr('id');
alert(spanId); // 1034
```

The whole function in turn can also be rewritten as follows:

```
$.get('notifications.php?n=1', function(responseText) {
    // Your code here.
});
```

See also the [jQuery tutorials.](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)

Comment: jQuery.html is not a function
$.html is not a function

Comment: Then `jQuery.growl` should have given the same problem. You need to load jQuery *before* this piece of Java code. Loading it is simple, just add the following line to HTML head, *before* any other scripts which depends on it: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: about the jquery.html is not a function error, it worked as jQuery('<div>').html(html)xxxxxxx;
instead of jQuery.html(html)xxxxx;

Comment: I didn't answered that. You apparently changed my answer in a wrong way. The `$()` is an alias for `jQuery()`, it's not the `$('<div>')`.